# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'dispsqldata' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\office\dispsqldata.php on line 30

Tags: php, forms, parsing, syntax-error

```
echo "<form action = "dispsqldata.php" method = "post">";
```

hello.I'm trying to Update and Display Records from a MySQL Database but in this line of code I get this .

Comment: You need to escape the `"` with a backslash: `echo "<form action=\"dispsqldata.php\" method=\"post\">";`

Comment: You can also change the outer " to ', but you just need to be aware of how quotes work together.

Comment: doesn't work. still the same.